# Server page priorities between index.php or index.html

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Can anybody tell me which file will be loaded first if we have 
1. index.php
2. index.html

files on server?

I want to install wordpress site on same domain, at the same time, I want to load my index.html page as a holding page until I properly launch website. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Apache (which I assume you do since you tagged this with `htaccess`) you can change your Apache config/htaccess's `DirectoryIndex` property to include the order of priority of index files:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
```

Here's the "algorithm":

- Does `index.html` exist in the current folder? If yes, then load it, if no, continue:
- Does `index.htm` exist in the current folder? If yes, then load it, if no, continue:
- Does `index.php` exist in the current folder? If yes, then load it, if no, continue:
- Does `index.php4` exist in the current folder? If yes, then load it, if no, continue:
- Does `index.php5` exist in the current folder? If yes, then load it, if no, continue:
- Send a `404` page not found error

Which means you can create an `index.html` file and then delete it once you want your site to run normally. Keep in mind that anyone can still access `index.php` if they wish - they just need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Thant actually depends on your [**`DirectoryIndex`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive. Set it up as:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

This will load `index.php` if it is available, if not then it will try to load `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Put in .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

The server will load the old html page first.