# Giving html file priority over index.php if called by visitor via browser url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla

I have a joomla site which starts with an index.php file that delivers the pages.

However I want to include a non-php page that would be delivered with priority if someone includes it when they type the URL in their browser.

For example.  If the page is bananas.html and the person types www.domainname.com/bananas I want that page to come up instead of any Joomla page.

I also want the "html" removed, so the page shows up as domainname.com/bananas (instead of www.domainname.com/bananas.html

Of course if they enter http://www.domain.com by itself, the joomla site would appear as usual.

I have only one page that I want this to happen.

There was a similar question here on stackoverflow which should be helpful to refer to:
[Server page priorities between index.php or index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563815/server-page-priorities-between-index-php-or-index-html)

It is an apache site and I have ftp access to the web root. So I can modify the htacess file.   The site is on a university server and I can have the IT person make any changes to any server files

Thanks for any help on this,

Rowby

Here is info about the site and the server:
PHP Built On      Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.i686 #1 SMP Mon Mar 3 13:33:00 EST 2014 i686
Database Version      5.5.38-MariaDB-log
Database Collation      latin1_swedish_ci
PHP Version      5.3.3
Web Server      Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
WebServer to PHP Interface      apache2handler
Joomla! Version      Joomla! 3.1.5 Stable [ Ember ] 01-August-2013 14:00 GMT
Joomla! Platform Version      Joomla Platform 12.2.0 Stable [ Neil Armstrong ] 21-September-2012 00:00 GMT
User Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.3

Answer (score 0):

Use Rewrite should do it:

RewriteRule ^bananas/(\d+)*$ ./bananas.html

Answer (score 0):

`DirectoryIndex` is not of much use here, because you want to load joomla unless you have a very good reason not to load it. That is, when the user requests a file that is present on the server. You can accomplish this with mod_rewrite ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)).

The following rule checks if the current requested file does not exist, then checks if the current requested file with `.html` appended does exist. If both of those are true, it internally rewrites the request to that file. This means that in the browser you'll see `http://example.com/bananas` and it will load `http://example.com/bananas.html` instead. If you request `http://example.com/`, it will check `http://example.com/.html`, which does not exist, which causes this rule to not match. Add this rule before any other rule you might have in the `.htaccess` file in your www-root.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Comment: Hi  Sumari8,  Thanks for this.  I'll check your docs link. Question: Since i only want this to work for one specific file "bananas.html" do I need to put bananas.html between the brackets, and also include the document root info in the brackets?  and re request URL instead of the bracks, etc?    In summary, do I need to use the "bracketed" placeholders rather than the specific file...?