# Which file is processed first, wordpress index.php or index.html?

Tags: wordpress, indexing, litespeed

I'm using LiteSpeed Web Server and wordpress. I would like to know that Which file is processed first, wordpress index.php or index.html? because i want to display coming soon (index.html) till i finished my wordpress site.

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563815/server-page-priorities-between-index-php-or-index-html) link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a useful under construction Plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/under-construction-page/

As a previous question on stackoverflow.com

The answer is.

Check it 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7873648/5441049

It really depends on the Server you're using. This is a matter of configuration. It's not that there's any advantage from using html vs php filetype.

You could say that the .html variation takes precedence due to the fact that it's the most basic web format.

If you're using Apache, just check the default .htaccess setup:

`DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.php index.htm default.html Default.htm default.html Default.html default.shtml Default.shtml page1.html index.pl index.cgi index.php3 index.phtml home.htm home.html home.shtml index.wml`

You can edit that and make it fit your needs.

Comment: I'm Using Lite Speed Server with Shared Hoting